# T-SQL GROUP BY also using JOIN, Aggregate and Outer Reference errors

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I'm learning SQL and trying to join several mock Hotel tables and make a simple query that shows a guest's concatenated name and the number of reservations they've made.

No matter how I try to restructure my query I keep getting one of two errors.

If I try this way:

```
SELECT 
    [Guests].FirstName + ' ' + [Guests].LastName AS 'Guest Name', 
    [ReservationsRooms].Reservation_ID
FROM 
    [ReservationsRooms]
JOIN 
    [Reservations] ON [ReservationsRooms].Reservation_ID = [Reservations].Reservation_ID
JOIN 
    [Guests] ON [Reservations].Guest_ID = [Guests].Guest_ID
GROUP BY 
    [Guests].Guest_ID
```

I get an error:

> Column 'Guests.FirstName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I thought maybe it was an ambiguity issue, so I also tried as follows:

```
SELECT 
    [Guests].FirstName + ' ' + [Guests].LastName AS 'Guest Name', 
    COUNT([ReservationsRooms].Reservation_ID) AS 'Reservations'
FROM 
    [ReservationsRooms]
JOIN 
    [Reservations] ON [ReservationsRooms].Reservation_ID = [Reservations].Reservation_ID
JOIN 
    [Guests] ON [Reservations].Guest_ID = [Guests].Guest_ID
GROUP BY 
    [Guests].Guest_ID, 'Guest Name'
```

But this also resulted in an error:

> Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

I am trying to make a query result that returns something like this:

```
Reservations    Guest Name
-------------------------------
4               Mack Simmer
3               Bettyann Seery
2               Duane Cullison
2               Aurore Lipton
2               Maritza Tilton
2               Joleen Tison
```

Specifically, I'd like ONLY these two columns in my query but can't seem to find a way of doing it.

Comment: It would seem some misunderstanding with how to use aggregations, you need to include sample data for your expected results as per [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why I *really* dislike people using literal strings for aliases; the ***only*** place this works is in the `SELECT`. `GROUP BY 'Guest Name'` doesn't mean "Group by the column aliased as `'Guest Name'`" it means "Group by the **literal string** `'Guest Name'`", which, unsurprisingly doesn't make any sense.

Even if you had used a better delimit identifier for your alias, either T-SQL's Brackets (`[]`) or ANSI-SQL's double quotes (`"`),you still wouldn't be able to do what you did as you can't reference a column by it's alias in the `GROUP BY` (for example `GROUP BY [Guest Name]` would produce the error *"Invalid column name 'Guest Name'"*). This is due to the [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement) and that the `GROUP BY` is processed several steps before the `SELECT` (steps 5 and 8 respectively), and so the alias has no context within the `GROUP BY`.

Instead you either need to `GROUP BY` the expression itself, or by the columns contained in the expression. I would personally use the latter here.

```sql
SELECT G.FirstName + ' ' + G.LastName AS GuestName, --Generally, avoid names that need delimit identification
       COUNT(RR.Reservation_ID) AS Reservations
FROM dbo.ReservationsRooms RR --Always schema qualify. Also aliases are good.
     JOIN dbo.Reservations ON RR.Reservation_ID = R.Reservation_ID
     JOIN dbo.Guests G ON R.Guest_ID = G.Guest_ID
GROUP BY G.FirstName,
         G.LastName,
         G.Guest_ID;
```

Alternatively, you could omit `G.FirstName` and `G.LastName` from the `GROUP BY` entirely and wrap the expression for `GuestName` inside a `MAX`:

```sql
MAX(G.FirstName + ' ' + G.LastName AS GuestName) AS GuestName
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this issue. I had no idea that I could not pivot on the alias I made for a column.  I appreciate the effort you took in making the issue clear for me.